# SimpleIoc (mvvmlight) - how to automatically register all classes implementing a particular interface

Tags: mvvm-light

Using SimpleIoc I want to automatically register all classes that implement a particular interface. I couldn't see a method on SimpleIoc's container to do this automatically so I put a some code together to iterate through the types to be registered. Unfortunately the code's not happy (see the commented line).

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom);

foreach (var type in types.Where(x=>x.IsClass))
{
    container.Register<IFoo, type>(); //this line won't compile as type can't be resolved by the compiler
}
```

I realise there are less elegant ways of registering classes (such as just hard coding "container.Register" to register each class to the interface) but I'd like to be able to add new implementations without having to keep updating the ioc installer code. It would also be useful, at some point, for me to be able to register classes in other assemblies using the same method.

Any idea what I have to change to make this build (or is there a simpler/more elegant way to do this)?

**UPDATE** fex posted this comment:

`"you can always iterate over types (like you do in your question) and create it with reflection (in your factory class) - (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(type); - in fact that's how service locators / ioc containers do it internally (in simplify)."`

I've now updated my code to the following which works, with one caveat (the implementations must have a parameterless constructor, and dependencies must therefore be satisfied by the factory that I'm then using to serve up instances implementing IFoo). I've included the factory registration too for info.

Updated code:

```
// Get the types that implement IFoo...
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom);

// Register these types and use reflection to instantiate each instance...
foreach (var type in types.Where(x=>x.IsClass))
{
    var t = type;
    container.Register(() => (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(t), t.ToString());
}

// Inject all registered instances of IFoo into IFooFactory when it's instantiated.
// Note that instances of IFoo must have their own dependencies satisfied via the
// factory at runtime before being served by the factory.
container.Register<IFooFactory>(
    () => new FooFactory(container.GetAllInstances<IFoo>()));
```

Comment: why would you like to register all interface implementation classes without any conditions? Do you use service location instead of dependency inversion?

Comment: @fex Sorry but I don't really understand your question. If it helps, I intend to use container.GetAllInstances<IFoo>() to pass all registered instances to a factory from where they will be served up.

Comment: @fex Also, the only condition is that the classes registered implement a particular interface (IFoo in this case). The interface itself has a method to allow the factory to determine whether that particular instance should be served up. I hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: don't know how to do it with SimpleIoC, you can always iterate over types (like you do in your question) and create it with reflection (in your factory class) - (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(type); - in fact that's how service locators / ioc containers do it internally (in simplify).